# A way to store sensitive data to disk, without (serious) fear of user tampering?

Tags: python, encryption, credentials

I'm writing an application that connects to twitter and uses the OAuth API, my issue is with storing the consumer_key and the consumer_key_secret

How can I safely store these values so they're difficult for the user to get to but still have ability to use them within my application?

I've had storing them within a pyc and encrypting them as suggestions so far, but I'm open to any other ideas.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have a desktop app, and you want to save user passwords, but prevent same or different user from seeing password plaintext?

Comment: Yes, I have a desktop app. I need to save user credentials and application credentials (not quite passwords but something similar), it's obviously not a great thing if the user can get to the application credentials.

Comment: oh you mean the twitter token tied to you somehow. Hmm. I think those are not meant to be in desktop apps.

Comment: They're required for desktop apps, unfortunately

Comment: I apologize if I am missing something, but what is wrong with [xAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth)? This seems like the perfect use case for it.

Comment: @Jathanism, quick glance suggests you are right on the money. You should post this as answer.

Comment: Doesn't xAuth also require static values be placed within the sourcecode?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to DRM (which is what you are describing) is to proxy the secured interaction through a server application on your own, controlled machine.  Since you're using OAuth, you can use the same authentication credentials against your own server as you would connecting directly to twitter.

The advantage to this approach is that there is no private key disclosure; you don't share your private key with your consumers, since that's stored on a remote server that they cannot read, and your consumers don't share their passwords with you (instead, they get an OAuth token which ties that particular login to your specific service).

Comment: How can this (practically) be done? At the moment I'm using the library tweepy to get my twitter stuff done, I would hate to have to roll my own library for this

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if I am missing something, but what is wrong with [xAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth)? This seems like the perfect use case for it. Your application would utilize (and therefore store) a consumer key (`oauth_consumer_key`) and there is no way around that: You must have something that uniquely identifies your app. You get the credentials from the user, pass these along and receive back `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` to allow you to make calls on the user's behalf.